# ERROR with flutter: CocoaPods not installed even if it is installed

Tags: flutter, installation, rubygems, cocoapods

I am trying to run my code on AndroidStudio by using Flutter but when I run it shows an error:

> Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.   CocoaPods is
> used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that
> responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.   Without CocoaPods,
> plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.   For more info, see
> https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins To install see
> https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation
> for instructions.
>
> CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Error launching
> application on iPhone 11.

flutter doctor shows that all is fine, I looked around a lot and tried lots of things like uninstall it and install it again, and tried adding:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.10.0

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: 0.39.14
```

and tried

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

and tried

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

But nothing worked, note that when I write "which pod" it shows the path, that means it exists right? then what is the problem? please help :(

Comment: Are you tried to run `pod` from terminal directly?

Comment: I am not that good with the terminal, can you specify more? @fartem

Comment: I am seeing this issue in Android Studio but it works fine in the terminal window.

Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1

Since it works fine in the terminal that mean CocoaPods are installed correct but somehow the environment inside of Android Studio cannot see them. Any help debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: @MeshAS The terminal command I am using is 'flutter run' where the current working directory is the base folder of the application.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to run `pod install` from the ios folder?

Comment: it shows some warnings, I solve them but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked with me is using android emulator, ios simulator still show the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution, but with still an answered question.  [See my question (and one partial solution) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930325/android-studio-doesnt-find-cocoapods-when-the-package-flutter-inappwebview-is)

The partial solution is: in Android Studio, click on the tab "Terminal" at the bottom of the IDE and in this pane, type `flutter run`. It does the same as the button **Run**, and Android Studio stopped complaining about CocaPods.

To stop the app, type `q` in the same terminal.