# Android Studio doesn't find CocoaPods when the package `flutter_inappwebview` is added

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-inappwebview, android-studio-bumblebee

Android Studio doesn't find CocoaPods when the package `flutter_inappwebview` is added to `pubspec.yaml`. It complains that CocoaPods is not installed.
But I can still build and run the app from the console with `flutter run`.

The minimal project to illustrate this bug is in https://github.com/kvutien/my_inappwebview

Any idea why?

### My development configuration

- Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip and macOS 12.1 Monterey
- `flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-LU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

### How to reproduce the bug

- In Android Studio, create **New Flutter Project**
- Set the SDK used in **File** > **Project Structure** > **Project** > **Project SDK**, select **Android API 32**
- Select an iOS virtual device
- Run the app to prove that it works, from the box.
- open `pubspec.yaml` add the following line to the section `dependencies` (that should be at line 29 of the template code), immediately below `sdk: flutter`,

```
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
```

- run `pub get` to update the dependencies
- run the app  with the **Run** buttton

Android Studio will complain

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPad mini (6th generation) in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPad mini (6th generation).
```

### Build and run still possible from Android Studio's Terminal

It's not a problem with missing CocoaPods, nor of missing PATH in configuration.

**Without changing anything in the code**, open the Terminal pane of Android Studio and type `flutter run`. The build will succeed and the app will run in the virtual device.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPad mini (6th generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                      2,243ms
Xcode build done.                                            8.5s
Syncing files to device iPad mini (6th generation)...               56ms
```

### But Android Studio behaves well, see sample `flutter_inappwebviewer` project in `pub.dev`

No need to run from the Terminal.

To prove it:

- In Android Studio, create **New Flutter Project**
- Set the SDK of the project as above
- Select an iOS virtual device
- Replace the initial `main.dart` with the sample code in `pub.dev`
- Add the dependency in `pubspec.yaml`
- Run `pub get`
- Build and run the app with the **Run** buttton

Android Studio will not complain about CocoaPods with this code.

The project to illustrate this is in https://github.com/kvutien/test_in_app_webview

### Any explanation is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved** on February 11, 2022.

The Android Studio upgrade **Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1a** for macOS M1 made the bug disappear. Running the build from the IDE `Run` button doesn't produce anymore the `CocoaPods missing` error message.